# Display network name in xmobar

Tags: xmonad

I was wondering if there is a way to display the currently connected WiFi and/or ethernet network name in xmobar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably want the Wireless plugin which comes with xmobar

http://projects.haskell.org/xmobar/#wireless-interface-args-refreshrate

In your config file, you'd have something like this in the `commands` list:

```
Run Wireless "wlan0" [ "-t", "<essid>" ] 10
```

Answer (score 4):

If your interface is named `wlan0` Then you can add this line

`Run Wireless "wlan0" [ "-t", "<essid>" ] 10`

to your commands list.

Access it in the template string through `%wlan0wi%`